# Misunderstanding bankers algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, bankers-algorithm

I am trying to understand how a banker's algorithm works. I have an example of how it works on my university slides, but I am not sure why one of processes (in my case `P4`) has been skipped. Should it not be checked like this at this point? Did I misunderstand something?

```
 P4 [3,2,2,3] <= [4,4,2,3]
```

My answer:

[image]

Answer from university slides:

[image: Answer from uni slide]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it should be part of the sequence and it will. It looks like your university slides only show the first step in the banking algorithm. That's why there's a comma after `P3` (screenshot from your slide):

[image]

As you noted already, once `P3` completes, the system will have more than enough resources to offer to `P4` because the availability vector will be updated as below:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Available | 3+1 | 3+1 | 0+2 | 2+1 |

And what `P4` will need is as follows:

[image]

You can obviously continue this sequence because after `P4` completes, `P0` may request resources and get approved too and so on.